# Create table for existing data using org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there a way of creating table for existing data using org-mode ?
Let's assume I have the following data

```
row1
row2
row3
```

And now I want to create a table of dimension 1x3 (col*row) on it.
The resulting output should be something like this:

```
| row1 |
|------|
| row2 |
| row3 |
```

Or even a variation of the above output should be ok.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select your data and type:

```
C-c |    (org-table-create-or-convert-from-region)
C-c -    (org-table-insert-hline)
```